Mouse cursor feels a little barrier at certain height in the external monitor
I am using Ubuntu 22.04 and an external monitor of QHD resolution whereas my laptop screen has FHD. I using in the "External Only" mode for display. It seems that the mouse feels a little resistance going below a certain point in my monitor, most likely where it would have been the end of the laptop monitor. How do I fix it?
